# run mysql command string which is stored in a variable

Tags: mysql, bash

In Bash I have following code:

```
alterCmd=alter table $tablename modify $columnname $columntype not null\; | mysql -ulogin -ppw -A $databasename
```

Normally I do:

```
echo alter table $tablename modify $columnname $columntype not null\; | mysql -ulogin -ppw -A $databasename
```

and it works. But I have to build up `alterCmd` and run it at the end.

How can I run the command that is stored in `alterCmd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alterCmd="alter table $tablename modify $columnname $columntype not null;"
echo "$alterCmd" | mysql -ulogin -ppw -A $databasename
```